# How do I filter an array object inside of a array of objects Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filtering

I am trying to filter the list by **offerings**

```
const questions = [
    { "id": 2616, "offerings": [{"code": "AA"},{"code": "AB"}]},
    { "id": 1505, "offerings": [{"code": "AA"},{"code": "ABC"}]},
    { "id": 1500, "offerings": [{"code": "AC"},{"code": "DC"}]}
];

const filterByArray = ['AB', 'DC'];
```

My expected outcome is to get back all the array elements based on what's passed in filterByArray

```
[
    { "id": 2616, "offerings": [{"code": "AA"},{"code": "AB"}]},
    { "id": 1500, "offerings": [{"code": "AC"},{"code": "DC"}]}
]
```

I tried filtering the array using

```
var filtered = questions.filter(function(element) {
    return element.offerings.filter(function(cd) {
       return filterByArray.indexOf(cd.code) > -1;
    }).length === filterByArray.length;
});

console.log(filtered)
```

But this keep returning all array elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const questions = [
    { "id": 2616, "offerings": [{"code": "AA"},{"code": "AB"}]},
    { "id": 1505, "offerings": [{"code": "AA"},{"code": "ABC"}]},
    { "id": 1500, "offerings": [{"code": "AC"},{"code": "DC"}]}
];

const filterByArray = ['AB', 'DC'];

const output = questions.filter(q => q.offerings.some(o => filterByArray.includes(o.code)));

console.log(output);
```